# How to make image visible and collapsed when i tap on grid(It is parent of image)?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone

Iam new to windows phone development. I have a grid, which contains a image. I need to make the image visible when i tap on grid(parent of image) and collapsed when i tapped for the second time.

My design as follows

```
<Grid x:Name="gridThriller" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="172" Margin="33,85,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="123"  Background="Transparent" Tap="selectThiller" >
            <Image Source="/Images/right.png" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Top" Stretch="None"  />
        </Grid>
        <Grid x:Name="gridAction" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="172" Margin="186,85,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="123"  Background="Transparent" Tap="selectThiller">
            <Image Source="/Images/right.png"  HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Top" Stretch="None"/>
        </Grid>
        <Grid x:Name="gridHorror" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="172" Margin="340,85,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="123"  Background="Transparent" Tap="selectThiller">
            <Image Source="/Images/right.png"  HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Top" Stretch="None"/>
        </Grid>
        <Grid x:Name="gridSciFi" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="172" Margin="33,283,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="123"  Background="Transparent" Tap="selectThiller">
            <Image Source="/Images/right.png"  HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Top" Stretch="None"/>
        </Grid>
        <Grid x:Name="gridRomantic" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="172" Margin="186,283,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="123"  Background="Transparent" Tap="selectThiller">
            <Image Source="/Images/right.png" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Top" Stretch="None"/>
        </Grid>
        <Grid x:Name="gridComedy" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="172" Margin="340,283,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="123"  Background="Transparent" Tap="selectThiller">
            <Image Source="/Images/right.png"  HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Top" Stretch="None"/>
        </Grid>
        <Grid x:Name="gridDrama" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="172" Margin="33,481,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="123"  Background="Transparent" Tap="selectThiller">
            <Image Source="/Images/right.png"  HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Top" Stretch="None"/>
        </Grid>
        <Grid x:Name="gridFantacy" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="172" Margin="186,481,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="123"  Background="Transparent" Tap="selectThiller">
            <Image Source="/Images/right.png"  HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Top" Stretch="None"/>
        </Grid>
        <Grid x:Name="gridAnimated" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="172" Margin="340,481,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="123"  Background="Transparent" Tap="selectThiller">
            <Image Source="/Images/right.png"   HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Top" Stretch="None"/>
        </Grid>
```

How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well it looks like you have the tap event for all of them pointing at the same method so thats an okay first start. If you want to continue down that path then what I would do is the following.

Inside your tap event

```
        foreach(Image item in (sender as Grid).Children)
        {
            if(item.Visibility == Visibility.Visible)
                item.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
            else
                item.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        }
```

NOTE# if you put ANYTHING else in those grid elements other than images this will explode. If you need to add other things then you will need to add separate logic above this to weed out images.